# create heat map from PCA coordinates in R

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap, text-mining, pca

I'd like to create a heat map on one variable against itself. However, I don't have it in matrix format. I have the PCA1 and PCA2 coordinates of each item and I'd like to know how I can create a heat map out of this. This is what my data looks like (where cluster is a k-means cluster classification)

```
ID                     PCA1             PCA2          cluster
echocardiography       -0.88            0.87          9
infarction             -0.18            0.57          7
carotid                1.13             -0.80         2
aorta                  -0.03            -0.06         5
myocardial             -0.72            -0.02         3
hemorrhage             0.23             -0.67         5
```

so basically I want a heat map between the IDs that shows (by possibly using PCA coordinate distance) how correlated each ID is.

note: the heat map should look something like this (vs a density heat plot):
[image]

Comment: Please, explain in details the structure of your heatmap. What variables do you need by row and by column ? What information do you need to display in each cell ?

Comment: I want the heat map to look similar to the purple heat map above. I'd like to correlate each ID against each other (aka row = ID and column = ID as well). The PCA coordinates on a plot show how correlated an ID is to another. So, I want each cell in the heat map to thus show perhaps the distance between each ID (using the PCA coordinates). The closer the ID is, the darker the cell to show correlation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibile solution. Hope it can help you.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("aorta", 
"carotid", "echocardiography", "hemorrhage", "infarction", "myocardial"
), class = "factor"), PCA1 = c(-0.88, -0.18, 1.13, -0.03, -0.72, 
0.23), PCA2 = c(0.87, 0.57, -0.8, -0.06, -0.02, -0.67), cluster = c(9L, 
7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L)), .Names = c("ID", "PCA1", "PCA2", "cluster"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# Define a distance function based on euclidean norm
# calculated between PCA values of the i-th and j-th items
dst <- Vectorize(function(i,j,dtset) sqrt(sum((dtset[i,2:3]-dtset[j,2:3])^2)), vectorize.args=c("i","j"))

# Here is the distance between echocardiography and infarction
dst(1,2,df)
# [1] 0.7615773
# This value is given by
sqrt(sum((df[1,2:3] - df[2,2:3])^2))

# Calculate the distance matrix
nr <- nrow(df)
mtx <- outer(1:nr, 1:nr, "dst", dtset=df)
colnames(mtx) <- rownames(mtx) <- df[,1]

# Plot the heatmap using ggplot2
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
mtx.long <- melt(mtx)
ggplot(mtx.long, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile()+xlab("")+ylab("")
```

[image]

Comment: this is beautiful. thank you. a few follow up questions: 1. how can I only show the cells who have a value of, let's say less than 0.5 (since the smaller the value, the smaller the distance, and thus the higher the correlation)? and 2. say that from the original sample dataset I posted, another variable called "group" dictates whether each ID in "MH" or "RN." how can I plot "MH" versus "RN?" thank you immensely for your help!

Comment: i can separate "MH" and "RN" into two different dataframes exactly like the one above...how could I use this data to plot, for instance, "RN" on the x-axis and "MH" on the y-axis?

Comment: I added this after your initial `mtx.long` code this for the answer to my second question: `mtx.long <- mtx.long[mtx.long$Var1 %in% RN_only_df$ID, ]` so that `Var1` only includes the RN terms.